# Function "doesn't recognise" a python class method

Tags: breadth-first-search, python-class

I have written a class that creates a board for a Klotski game and I want to use breadth-first search to solve the given problem. Here is a bit of my code:

**EDIT and DISCLAIMER:** I added all the **relevant** class methods and functions in the code, although it is not optimized and I tried to make it shorter...

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Klotski:

    def __init__(self, board, history=[]):

        #Initialize the board as a matrix
        self.board = deepcopy(board)

        #Append the move history to an array
        self.history = [] + history + [self.board] 
    
        
    def children(self):        # returns the possible moves

        moves = [self.try_move_down] # list of move functions

        children = []
        for row in range(len(self.board)):          # will try to move every piece in every direction and return the possible moves
            for col in range(len(self.board[row])):
                for func in moves:
                    child = func(row, col)
                    if child:
                        children.append(child)
        return children
    
    def is_objective(self):                 # checks if the puzzle is complete
        if self.board[3][1]==4 and self.board[4][2]==4:
            return True
        return False
```

In the **moves** list there are 4 different directions, but they are structured very similarly. I will include only 1 of the relevant **moves** methods:

```
def try_move_down(self, row, col):              # will check the current piece to see if it can be moved downwards
        if row<4:
            if self.board[row][col]==1:               # if the piece type is 1x1
                if self.board[row+1][col]==0:
                    return self.move_down(row, col)
                else:
                    return None
            elif self.board[row][col]==4:             # if the piece type is 2x2
                if (col>0 and self.board[row][col-1]==4) or (row>0 and self.board[row-1][col]==4):
                    return None
                if self.board[row+2][col]==0 and self.board[row+2][col+1]==0:
                    return self.move_down(row, col)
                else:
                    return None
                        
                        
    def move_down(self, row, col):      # will move the current piece upwards
        state=Klotski(self.board, self.move_history)
        if state.board[row][col]==1:                         # piece type 1x1
            state.board[row][col]=0
            state.board[row+1][col]=1
            
        elif state.board[row][col]==4:                       # piece type 2x2
            state.board[row+2][col]=4
            state.board[row+2][col+1]=4
            state.board[row][col]=0
            state.board[row][col+1]=0
        return state.board
```

The problem arose when I created this function:

```
def bfs(problem:Klotski):                                           # problem(Klotski) - the initial state
    queue = [problem]
    visited = set()                                         # to not visit the same state twice

    while queue:
        current = queue.pop(0)
        visited.add(str(current))

        if current.is_objective():                          # found the best solution
            return current

        child_list=current.children()
        for child in child_list:               
            if str(child) not in visited:                        # avoid visiting the same state twice
                queue.append(child)

    return None
```

When I run this cycle, which should print the number of steps it took to solve the puzzle, as well as the board state at every step:

```
def print_sequence(state):
    print("Steps:", len(state.history) - 1) # prints the sequence of states
    for move in state.history:
        print(move)
        print()

print_sequence(bfs(Klotski([[1,4,4,1], [1,4,4,1], [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1], [1,0,0,1]])))
```

I get on my terminal this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\...\Code.py", line 229, in <module>
    print_sequence(bfs(Klotski([[1,4,4,1], [1,4,4,1], [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1], [1,0,0,1]])))
  File "c:\Users\...\Code.py", line 216, in bfs
    if current.is_objective():                          # found the best solution
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_objective'
```

What should I do to fix my problem?...

P.S.:Sorry for the long post and I'm a beginner. I tried to make the post more readable and shorter in size (even though it's still basically a massive code dump...). Also if there's a shorter way to recreate the problem feel free to tell me.

Comment: Somehow your queue is getting a list object added to it, rather than a `Klotski` instance.  I don't see this happening anywhere in the code you posted, so it must be in one of the move methods that you omitted.  (Your colleague's change completely broke the program.  `current.is_objective` is always true (since this doesn't actually call the method), so the program exited before it got to the point where the list got added to the queue.)

Comment: Hi, thx for answering one of my questions. Also I have updated the post to include the omitted code that I mentioned, but it is kinda long and may hurt someone who knows how to optimize code. I'd be very grateful if you could take a look at it. <3

Comment: " But "is_objective", as far as I know, is not an attribute, but instead a class method." Methods *are attributes*. A method is a kind of attribute.

Comment: In any case, the problem is that where you believe you have a `Klotski` instance you actually have a `list` instance.

Comment: Ooooh I didn't know that... But even still, the method is defined so I thought it should work. The _current_ variable represents the current state of the board and should be able to "replace" the self attribute in the class, or so I believe...

Comment: Listen, you just dumped your whole code here, and provided a snippet of the error message (which doesn't include the stack trace, which would tell us exactly where this is happening). Please put a little bit of effort in providing a [mcve].

Comment: " But even still, the method is defined so I thought it should work." **not if you call it on a `list` instance**.

Comment: Then the problem is in the children_list() method because it returns a list of list instances rather than a list of class instances?

Comment: Your move methods are not returning the `Klotski` instances they create, they are returning the `board` attribute from that instance - which is a list.

Comment: I'm new and I'm trying my best... I'll keep editing the post to make it more readable. But thank you for the feedback

Comment: Alright, I tried to shorten the post. Since you guys pointed out that the methods are returning the wrong kind of attribute I'll try to start by changing that in my code and update the post again if I get any results. If I understood correctly, I'll try to change what the **moves** and the **children_list** return.

Comment: other problems apart, your init method is like this `def __init__(self, board, history=[]):` which will malfunction at the moment you create 2 instances of your board. Do not use mutable objects as default arguments in Python: in this case the _same_ list will be used across all instances, leading to all kinds of problems.

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone who answered my questions and gave me advice not only on my code, but on my post as well. I know this wasn't a very good post so thank you so much for taking time out of you busy schedules. I have fixed the bugs in my code AND I understood the issue, which I believe is the most important takeaway from this.

Answer (score 0):

here!

When cheking the positions you append the items returned by `. children()`, which are the return of the movement functions, and `move_down` returns you the `state.board` - which is a list.

Probably you want these items returned by `children` to be instances of the board - so it should return `state`, not `state.board`. (`state` would have the method that is missing).

All in all, just change the last line here (and in other omitted move functions):

```
    def move_down(self, row, col):      # will move the current piece upwards
        state=Klotski(self.board, self.move_history)
        if state.board[row][col]==1:                         # piece type 1x1
           ...
        elif state.board[row][col]==4:                       # piece type 2x2
           ...
        return state    # <- changed this from `return state.board`
```

Also, do not ever use mutable objects as default arguments when declaring a function or method - change your `__init__` to:

```
    def __init__(self, board, history=None):

        history = history or []  # This `[]` is inside the function and is a new list each time the method is executed. 
        #Initialize the board as a matrix
        self.board = deepcopy(board)

        #Append the move history to an array
        self.history = history + [self.board]
```